# It's possible to fetch the amount of people I'm blocking on twitter?

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

I want to display the number of people I'm blocking on twitter on my website, how would I have to approach that with the twitter API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to do the following:

- [apply for access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access) to the Twitter API
- build a server-side app that uses your user auth tokens to check your account for those it is blocking, using the [`blocks/list` endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/mute-block-report-users/api-reference/get-blocks-list)
- count the number of entries that are returned in the results JSON. Your app may need to make multiple calls to the endpoint if there are multiple pages of results, so then total those counts.
- embed the result into your website